# Menu displaying incorrectly in chrome and seems to work in internet explorer

Tags: css

I have a drop down menu employed in my website. For some reason there is a bullet infront of all the menu items and there is too much padding in the drop down items. However, it seems to be working fine expect for the bullet in `Internet Explorer`.

When I check the element using inspect in `google chrome`, I found that some properties are inherited from `user agent stylesheet`. I check for the answer to this problem in the google. There were several answers and among which one was to insert `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`.

My website link is `http://nepal-kathmandu.com/swayambhunath.php`.

Comment: Please post a complete code example in your question. Also, when something works in IE but not in Chrome, odds are there's something very wrong with the code.

Comment: What is your question? Please post at least a working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should probably try list-style: none in your css for the  tag